# replace icon with other custome icon in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

15.3  .I want change icon 
 i want  replace close icon  with  ban icon
iam use this code. but don't work.

```
  $('span fa fa-fw fa-ban').removeClass('span fa fa-fw fa-ban').addClass('span fa fa-fw fa-close');
```

this demo https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/207/

Comment: Please do not refer to external sources to show your problem. These are not permanent. Other users should also get the opportunity to understand your problem. However, this does not work if the problem is no longer accessible.

Comment: Could you describe **where** you want replace `fa-ban` to `fa-close`? It will be used in navigator bar (as Cancel button), as action button (as Cancel button) and in Add/Edit form during form editing. Which one you want to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to replace any icon after the grid is created. Instead of that you can customize your own icon set based on existing one (based on `iconSet: "fontAwesome"`, for example) and to use it. [The wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8) provides an example of such customizing. Modification of the example for your case will be the following

```
$.jgrid.icons.customFontAwesome = $.extend(true, {},
     $.jgrid.icons.fontAwesome,
     {
         nav: { cancel: "fa-close" },
         actions: { cancel: "fa-close" },
         form: { cancel: "fa-close" }
     }
 );
```

The example above defines new icon set under the name `customFontAwesome`, which have the same content as `fontAwesome` (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.3/js/grid.base.js#L464-L535) of source code) with exception of 3 icons, where `fa-ban` were used by default.

After that you need just replace the option `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` to `iconSet: "customFontAwesome"` and jqGrid will use the icons. See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/237/

I changed additionally in the demo the code fragment where you overwrite `$.jgrid.showModal` method to the following:

```
 $.extend($.jgrid, {
     showModal: function (h) {
         // properties of h
         //   w: (jQuery object) The modal element
         h.w.css({
             left: "3%", // new left position of ERROR dialog
             top: "3%"   // new top position of ERROR dialog
         });
         h.w.show();
     }
 });
```

It seems to me that it's what you want to have before.